# LLVM optimizer can't handle simple case?

Tags: c++, optimization, llvm

I wrote a .cpp file shown below

```
int main() {
  int a, b;
  scanf( "%d", &b );

  for ( int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++ ) {
    a = 0;
    if ( b > 10 )
      a = 3;
  }
  return a;
}
```

then I compiled this code by clang with -O3 option, the output .ll file is

```
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %b = alloca i32, align 4
  %call = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i32* %b)
  %0 = load i32* %b, align 4, !tbaa !1
  %cmp1 = icmp sgt i32 %0, 10
  %. = select i1 %cmp1, i32 3, i32 0
  ret i32 %.
}
attributes #0 = { nounwind "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
```

This output is good. LLVM optimizer stripped the meaningless `forloop` from the code, and then assigned three or zero to return value directly.

Now I try another case like

```
int main() {
  int a, b;
  scanf( "%d", &b );

  for ( int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++ ) {
    a = 0;
    if ( true ) // I modified here only
      a = 3;
  }
  return a;
}
```

and the output file is

```
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %b = alloca i32, align 4
  %call = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i32* %b)
  br label %for.cond

for.cond:                                         ; preds = %for.cond, %entry
  %a.0 = phi i32 [ 0, %entry ], [ 3, %for.cond ]
  %i.0 = phi i32 [ 0, %entry ], [ %inc, %for.cond ]
  %inc = add nsw i32 %i.0, 1
  %exitcond = icmp eq i32 %inc, 1001
  br i1 %exitcond, label %for.end, label %for.cond

for.end:                                          ; preds = %for.cond
 ret i32 %a.0
}
attributes #0 = { nounwind "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
```

Even though this code is easier to analyze (branch is always taken), LLVM optimizer doesn't strip meaningless `forloop`

If I was optimizer, I would like to generate this optimized code like

```
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %b = alloca i32, align 4
  %call = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i32* %b)
  ret i32 3
}
```

Can anyone tells me why the optimizer can't analyze a simpler code?

Comment: Sounds like a optimzer bug to me

Comment: what version what platform?

Comment: I'm no assembly god, but this looks good to me (the colors are nice)  https://godbolt.org/g/qxf6jR  -- I ran through every version of clang on the site and couldn't reproduce it with any of them.

Answer (score 5):

I've tested your code snippet with `llvm 3.9` and it generates:

```
define i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = bitcast i32* %1 to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start(i64 4, i8* %2) #3
  %3 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i32* nonnull %1)
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64 4, i8* %2) #3
  ret i32 3
}
```

As hinted by MikeMB, I guess it is a bug in the optimizer that has now been fixed. What was your `llvm` version?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/qxf6jR -- the color coding makes it blatantly obvious for even someone like me

Comment: 3.4 and 3.8, both of them have same results. According to your testing, I think this bug is fixed in 3.9 but I haven't updated my LLVM. Thanks for your testing :)